# Showing concavity of $f_p(x_1, \cdots x_n) = \mathbb{E}|\epsilon_1x_1^{1/p} + \cdots + \epsilon_nx_n^{1/p}|^p$ for Rademacher $\epsilon_i$

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose $\epsilon_i$ are iid Rademacher RVs (RVs with $0.5$ probability of being $1,-1$ each). Then let $p \in (3, \infty)$ and consider $f_p(x_1 \cdots x_n) = \mathbb{E}|\epsilon_1x_1^{1/p}+\cdots + \epsilon_nx_n^{1/p}|^p$ is a concave function on $\mathbb{R}^n_{\geq 0}$ (i.e the $x_i$ are $\geq 0$).

I've played with and applied Minkowski and other inequalities and I suspect it's just a matter of making the right simplifications with nothing deep behind it; but I'm not really getting anywhere with it- so I'm asking here for help.

Comment: Where does this question come from?

Comment: And is the exponentiation inside or outside the expectation?

Comment: The exponentiation is inside the expectation. Unfortunately the question comes from a HW problem that I've struggled and run out of patience with. Hope that's fine.

Comment: It is between you and your God, but my question was more along the lines of whether there was any context we could use.

Comment: I gave all the information required. It shouldn't need any pre-reqs beyond basic $L_p$ space stuff and maybe some law of large numbers stuff.